# Escape character causing a issue in the csv table and creating a new column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-bigquery, google-cloud-storage

I am using the following code to load csv data from GCS to big query.

```
try{
      
        source="gs://folder/all*";
        ProjectId="project";
        datasetId="dataset";
        tableId="table";
        schema={"configuration.load.autodetect":'true'};
             
        var tableReference = BigQuery.newTableReference();
        tableReference.setProjectId(ProjectId);
        tableReference.setDatasetId(datasetId);
        tableReference.setTableId(tableId);

        var load = BigQuery.newJobConfigurationLoad();
        load.setDestinationTable(tableReference);
        load.setSourceUris([source]);
        load.setSourceFormat('CSV');
        load.allowQuotedNewlines=true;
        load.setAutodetect(true);
        load.setMaxBadRecords(100000);
        load.setWriteDisposition('WRITE_TRUNCATE');

        var configuration = BigQuery.newJobConfiguration();
        configuration.setLoad(load);

        var newJob = BigQuery.newJob();
        newJob.setConfiguration(configuration);

        var job = BigQuery.Jobs.insert(newJob, ProjectId);

    }catch(err){ 
        Logger.log('Table upload error: %s', err);  
    }
```

The code works and loads the file but some rows have values that include "(`\`)" which shifts the value by 1 column. That leads to addition of another column to the data.

eg. If the Device name is "Google ChromeBook (CS\059)" then it splits the value into "Google ChromeBook (CS`\`" and "059" which shift the next column. Is there a way to handle that to make sure the value does not shift because of "`\`".

So, this is happening in the table,

How the table is supposed to be:

| User | Device_Name | Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Google ChromeBook (CS\059) | GB |
| 1235 | Pixel XL | AU |
| 1236 | HTC 320 | CA |

This is what's happening,

| User | Device_Name | Country | string_0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | Google ChromeBook (CS\ | 059) | GB |
| 1235 | Pixel XL | AU | \N |
| 1236 | HTC 320 | CA | \N |

So, basically this is what's happening to all the rows which have a backslash in the column as a value.

If I put the Max Records as 0, the table won't load up because it gives the error " Found 33 column(s) while expected 32. ".

Comment: What is the question? Please show what you tried to solve the problema and add a brief description of your search efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: How does the addition of a `\\` lead to the addition of another column?

Comment: Please provide data examples to explain the problem in more detail.

Comment: @MetaMan I just added table examples. Is there a way to stop the split of the value in the table?

Comment: Try replacing all \ with -.

Comment: The file that I am working on would update regularly, so manually changing the values would not be possible.